# Upload files with Delphi XE7 TRESTRequest without AddFile

Tags: delphi, multipartform-data, delphi-xe7, rad-studio, c++builder-xe7

Using RAD Studio XE7, I need to post files using the `TRESTRequest` component.

Unfortunately, I did not find a `AddFile()` method in this version of the component.

So, I have to find a solution that allows me to do this using the `TRESTRequest`'s `Parameters` and `Body` options.

I can't use other components, like `TIdHTTP`, because there is a *Token authentication* management that I would like to avoid redoing in other ways.

So, my question is: Does there exist a way, in RAD Studio XE7, to post a file using the `multipart/form-data` format, where you select the file and upload it?

As with the `TRESTRequest.AddFile()` method of later RAD Studio versions, the filename will have to be passed along with the file contents, because the REST server expects this.

Comment: If `TRESTRequest` in XE7 doesn't natively support `AddFile()`, then chances are that you are going to have to *manually* format the *entire* MIME body yourself from scratch. What *Token authentication* is `TRESTRequest` managing for you that you can't do in other HTTP components, like `TIdHTTP` (which natively supports `multipart/form-data` via `TIdMultipartFormDataStream`)?

Comment: @RemyLebeau thanks. I'll find examples to format the MIME body and set up a class method in my unit, in order to upload _form-data_ files.<BR>The _Token authentication_ is _Bearer_. My initial goal was to use _TRESTRequest_ component only. However, any suggestions in order to use alternative _TIdHTTP_ methods are welcome. Here is the piece of code used for TRESTRequest authentication: Param=RESTRequest->Params->AddItem(); Param->ContentType=ctAPPLICATION_JSON; Param->name="Authorization"; Param->Value="Bearer "+MyToken; Param->Options<<poDoNotEncode; Param->Kind=pkHTTPHEADER;

Comment: `TIdHTTP` lets you specify custom headers, for example: `IdHTTP->Request->BasicAuthentication = false; IdHTTP->Request->CustomHeaders->Values["Authorization"] = "Bearer "+MyToken;`